# Solve the linear congruence $28x \equiv 63 \pmod {105}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Solve the linear congruence $28x \equiv    63 \pmod {105} $

Now $gcd(28,105)=7$ and $7|63$ so it has solution 
The congruence is equivalent to $4x \equiv 9 \pmod {15}$
Now $gcd(4,15)=1$
So $4u+15v=1$
Here $u=4$, $v=-1$ 
Implies $4(4)+15.(-1)=1$
Implies $4(4) \equiv 1 \pmod {15}$
Now $4(36) \equiv 9 \pmod {15}$
Now there are how many solution of $28x \equiv 63 \pmod {105} $ .what they are..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already noted, you're trying to solve $15|4x-9$, which is equivalent to $15|4x-24$ and hence $15|x-6$.

Comment: But how to find number of solutions

Comment: And why we use your mentioned form but not mine

Comment: Just for knowledge

Comment: @John757 Each residue class modulo $15$ corresponds to seven classes modulo $105$ - each of these seven classes reduces to the same thing modulo $15$. More concretely $x=6, 21, 36 \dots $. Study this example and you should be able to identify the general pattern.

Comment: @mark OK I got it thanks