# How do I find the mod of this question?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can someone help me with $109x\equiv 24\pmod{26}$? I don't really know what to do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look up the questions on $ax\equiv b\bmod m$ here at this site! See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829611/solve-the-linear-congruence-28x-equiv-63-pmod-105?rq=1). What have you tried ?

Comment: i tried bashing it by adding 26 to 24 to get a multiple of 109.

Comment: $109\equiv 5\pmod{26}.$ $24\equiv 50\pmod{26}.$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Modulo $26$, you may add or subtract multiples of $26$

Comment: $109x = 24 + 26y$..  $(4*26+5)x = 24+26y$.. $5x = 24+26(y-4)$..$5x=4+4*5+26(y-4)$..$5(x-4)=4+26(y-4)$.. $5(x-4)=30+26(y-5)$..$x-4=6+\frac{26(y-5)}5$. That's an integer but $5$(prime) doesn't divide $26$ so $5|y-5$ (BTW we don't give a fig about what $y$ is)..$x-4=6+26*\frac{y-5}5$.. $x =10 +26*\frac{y-5}5$..$x\equiv 10\pmod 16$..Verify: $109*10\equiv 1090\equiv24+41*26\equiv 24\pmod{26}$.

Comment: "i tried bashing it by adding 26 to 24 to get a multiple of 109" Good Idea.  But notice that $109 > 26$ so try bashing that down to $109=104 + 5$ so $109x\equiv 5x \equiv 24\equiv 24+26\equiv 50\pmod {26}$.  Now **DON'T**  *assume* you can do division, but note that if $x \equiv 10\pmod{26}$ then $5*10\equiv 50 \equiv 24\pmod 26$.  Or $109*10\equiv1090=41*26 + 24\equiv 24\pmod{26}$.